# Compile time configuration using if-statements

Tags: c, gcc, embedded

In the embedded C world, we frequently store configuration details in headers so that a library can be built for a specific task, minimizing overhead and compiled size.

One example would be:

```
//libnameConf.h
#define LIBNAME_WAVE LIBNAME_A

typedef enum {
  LIBNAME_A,
  LIBNAME_B,
  LIBNAME_C
} libname_wave_t;
```

---

```
//libname.c
double coef_arr_a[100] = {...};
double coef_arr_b[100] = {...};
double coef_arr_c[100] = {...};

if (LIBNAME_WAVE == LIBNAME_A) {
  somestruct.waveCoefs = coef_arr_a;
  //do other coef_arr_a specific stuff
} else if (LIBNAME_WAVE == LIBNAME_B) {...}
```

For this particular case we're using an if-statement that the compiler will obviously collapse which is a good thing because we only want a reference to coef_arr_a so that the others won't be compiled into the binary and take up space.

Unfortunately, this yields the warning

```
warning: comparison between 'enum <anonymous>' and 'enum <anonymous>' [-Wenum-compare]
```

Is there a better way that avoids this warning?

Comment: provide a name for your enum?

Comment: Edited the enum for clarity.  Having a name doesn't make a difference in the warning.

Comment: I'm not really one to recommend using the preprocessor or macros, but for things like this it's really the most common, and will be certain to be evaluated at compile-time. Your `if` statements are not *required* to be evaluated or optimized by the compiler, even though a good compiler probably does it. Especially, there's no requirement that the compiler actually have to omit the code for the non-taken branches. It might still do that, even though it just jumps over it.

Comment: In a normal case I would agree that relying on the compiler to get rid of code you don't intend to run is sub optimal.  In this case though, we can easily prove that it's happening by looking at the generated map file and/or watching the JTAG probe freak out when you try to load a huge .elf onto a tiny Cortex M0

I should also mention that the macros to perform this kind of optimization are kind of messy but that's more subjective

Comment: In the original version of the code the `enum` lacked a terminating `;` but I get no warnings or errors from a simple implementation of the update (MSVC).

Comment: Interesting.  GCC doesn't seem to like this which is our target compiler

Answer (score 1):

How about using macros only instead of using variables and enumerations.

```
//libnameConf.h
#define LIBNAME_A
// #define LIBNAME_B // Uncomment this line and both comment the above line while changing libs.
```

Then we use several conditional compilation statements like this.

```
//libname.c
double coef_arr_a[100] = {...};
double coef_arr_b[100] = {...};

#ifdef LIBNAME_A
  somestruct.waveCoefs = coef_arr_a;
  //do other coef_arr_a specific stuff
#endif
#ifdef LIBNAME_B
  somestruct.waveCoefs = coef_arr_b;
#endif
```

Comment: There's a reference on wikipedia. We can search the topic "C preprocessor". As that page say we can use more complex conditional compilation statements to fit our requirement.: Using #ifdef xxx...#elif defined xxx ... #endif

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need [conditional compilaiton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_compilation) in C but the way you're doing it is not correct. Conditional compilation is a concept of the [preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocessor) which is run before the compiler. The point of preprocessor is to manipulate the source code before it is fed to the compiler. Since you haven't used any preprocessor conditionals, all the source code is fed to the compiler regardless of your compile-time conditionals. You should definitely use preprocessor conditionals to reduce your binary.